# Why assigning 100% of viewport width among elements breaks the look?

Tags: css

I am trying to design a two column theme with CSS3 viewport. My css and html looks like -

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#one{
    width: 20vw;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
}

#two{
    width: 80vw;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
}

<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
```

However, with this the divs are displayed one after another. But if I remove `height:100vh`, they are displayed side-by-side as was expected. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

```css
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#one{
    width: 20vw;
    height:100vh;
    float: left;
}

#two{
    width: 80vw;
    height:100vh;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the height of the elements to 100% of the viewport height, this causes a vertical scrollbar to appear. The vertical scrollbar makes the viewport narrower, which causes your elements to wrap. One way to solve this is to set `overflow-y: hidden` on the body element, which prevents the scroll bar from appearing:

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#one {
    width: 20vw;
    height:100vh;
    float: left;
}

#two {
    width: 80vw;
    height:100vh;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
```

A better solution (in my opinion) is to create a wrapper around your divs to prevent them from wrapping:

```css
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100vw;
}

#one {
    width: 20vw;
    height:100vh;
    float: left;
}

#two {
    width: 80vw;
    height:100vh;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">one</div>
    <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:0;
    margin:0
}

:root,body{width: 100vw; height: 100vh}
```

Hier is a [good reading](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) about it by paul

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding:0;
    margin:0
}

:root,body{width: 100vw; height: 100vh}

#one,#two{
    float: left;
    height: 100vh
}
#one{
    width: 20vw;
    background: red
}

#two{
    width: 80vw;
    background: green
}
```

```html
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because (stupidly) browsers ignore the scrollbar for viewport units. That means that your two `div`s are making up all available screenspace but the scrollbar needs its space too. So `div#two` will break into a new line.

There are issues filed for this on Mozilla, for example

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=811403

Answer (score -1):

```
height: 100vh;
```

this sets the height to 100vh, meaning it sets it as heigh as the viewport is.

using `20vw` and `80vw` equals `100vw` meaning it would be logical to place on below the other, because the vw is 100%.

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#one{
    width: 20vw;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
}

#two{
    width:79vw;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
}
```

try using this